# Access 2013 and Sharepoint 2013 Web Integration

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

First of all, this question is somewhat high level (or as I also like to call it.. Vague). I have worked in a few IT departments and every place I go I seem to see the same thing, users are looking for a way to bring there old access databases for things like IT inventory and task management onto the web. SharePoint is the obvious choice, but it seems it can get about 90% of the way there out of the box. Then all of a sudden you hit a dead end and your only option is to bust out visual studio to complete the rest, obviously not great when the end user has done the first 90% themselves ! The real restrictions seem to be on linking lists, permissions on individual list columns etc

I see SharePoint 2013 and Access 2013 can now be linked/integrated, has anybody tried this sort of stuff and is it really doable for an end user like Microsoft say ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The abilities that Access 2013 has compared to the Sharepoint "web app" feels limited. **You cannot use the VBA code in any of your forms and must deal with SQL and Macro Commands only**. So if you use a lot of VBA you will have to redo most of your project and learn how to use the macro's. Personally i have used VBA to do most of my work but like you need it to be out on the web now.

My main fear with spending time using Access and Sharepoint is not being able to custom code pieces in. If i run into a limitation i don't believe there is another option.

- [Example Web App](https://011588-f782957bb760fe.sharepoint.com/personal/jsharpe_011588_onmicrosoft_com/My%20New%20App/default.aspx#Tile=Contacts&View=Contacts%20List)
- [When Access web apps 2013 gets Johnny frustrated...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0ac978d6-51f1-47f7-8e01-4523f0fe49fb/when-access-web-apps-2013-gets-johnny-frustrated)
- [Discontinued features and modified functionality in Access 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-access-2013-HA102749226.aspx)

The interface is different and from an overview seems more effective for simple input and view forms, something easily used on a phone. For instance this is a default contact form in its edit view in Access.

[image: Interface Image 1]

Most of your control is centered around the custom buttons on top which i found to be limited to on click macros and simple edit / save data actions.

[image: Interface Image 2]

Your options for forum design also is limited, however there is an added bonus of an autocomplete search input bar which is absent from the desktop based projects.

[image: Interface Image 2]

In addition the macro list options have been reduced some.

[image: Macro List]

Comment: Could you help me to better understand `The abilities that Access 2013 has compared to the Sharepoint "web app" feels limited. ` i understood that a sharepoint web app can have more features than an Access 2013 db that is running on sharepoint. Did you mean this or did you mean a web app can have more features than a standalone access 2013 db? Are there any differences between  a standalone access 2013 compared to 2010?

Is `Access 2013 web app` the name for a different program or is it one database-option inside the classic office 2013 desktop app?